# SpriteKit Particle Emitter Multi Image

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skemitternode

I'm trying to use SKSprite Particle Emitter with Swift.

But I want use a number of different textures in my emitter.

Is it possible to: have many images, and, have the emitter use the images randomly, instead of using only one image?

Thanks

Comment: If I understand you correctly, no, you can't do that. The most you can get is to manually change the [texture](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKEmitterNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKEmitterNode/particleTexture) (particleTexture) using SKAction for example, but by doing that, the new texture will be applied to all of the existing particles. And I guess that is not what you want...

Comment: Yes i have tried to change manually texture and of course it's applied in all particles. But thank you for confirming it's not possible. I will try do this manually so.

Comment: Something you can do is have multiple particle emitters in the same location,  that is how I handle my "confetti" type effects

Comment: This is old,  you can treat an SKTexture like an atlas and have the shader select parts of the texture

Comment: @Knight0fDragon there's a bounty waiting on this question if you pop in an answer - at worst you could just paste in your comment as an answer!

Comment: same for you @Whirlwind - it does sound like the answer is simply NO (unless you do it in a shader)

Comment: Is there an example of how to do this?

Comment: Why not just use multiple copies of the same emitter but with different textures??

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you designed your emitter with one texture and saved it as "original.sks", and you have an array with the textures called `textures`:

```
var emitters:[SKEmitterNode] = []
for t in textures {
    let emitter = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "original.sks")!
    emitter.particleTexture = t
    emitter.numParticlesToEmit /= CGFloat(emitters.count)
    emitter.particleBirthRate /= CGFloat(emitters.count)
    emitters.append(emitter)
}
```

Now you have an array of emitters instead of a single one. Whatever you'd do with your emitter, just do it with the array:

```
// What you'd do with a single emitter:
addChild(someNormalEmitter)
someNormalEmitter.run(someAction)
...
    

// How to do the same with the array:
emitters.forEach {
    self.addChild($0)
    $0.run(someAction)
...
}
```

Of course, you can also subclass `SKEmitterNode` so that it contains other `SKEmitterNode` children and propagates all the usual emitter methods and actions and properties to the children… depending on your needs.