# Is it possible to animate SKTexture with images?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skemitternode, sktexture

I created a SKEmitterNode and I want the particleTexture property to animate images.

This is what I'm trying, but it is only showing the first image:

```
let animationImages = [UIImage(named: "image1")!, UIImage(named: "image2")!]

  let imageView = UIImageView()
  imageView.image = UIImage.animatedImage(with: animationImages, duration: 1)
  imageView.startAnimating()

  emitter.particleTexture = SKTexture(image: imageView.image!)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your last line will always return the same "main" image, regardless of the animation. This was confirmed elsewhere on this site already, but see also [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimageview/1621069-image) of `UIImageView.image`.

But even if you did manage to obtain the current image, it would still be a one-time assignment, and the texture wouldn't update automatically; that's something you will need to do yourself; as Apple puts it in [Animating a Sprite by Changing its Texture](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skspritenode/animating_a_sprite_by_changing_its_texture) in Apple's `SpriteKit` reference:

> A sprite’s texture property points to its current texture. You can change this property to point to a new texture.

#### Supposed solution: particle action (doesn't seem to work since iOS 9)

Luckily, there's an `SKAction` to do just that (see the last link for some details), and it can **theoretically** even be applied to `SKEmitterNode` particles (something I just found out as I was about to tell you the opposite):

```
let animationTextures = [SKTexture(imageNamed: "image1"),
                         SKTexture(imageNamed: "image2"),
                         SKTexture(imageNamed: "image3")]
let animationAction = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.animate(with: textures, timePerFrame: 0.1))
emitter.particleAction = animationAction
```

**EDIT: It doesn't work, and hasn't worked for years: `particleAction`s are simply being ignored.** It's quite incredible that Apple wouldn't fix such an obvious bug for half a decade, but this seems to be the case.

#### Workaround: implement your own emitter

`SKEmitterNode`s have a lot going for them (this bug notwithstanding):

- Particles are lightweight, stripped-down `SKSpriteNode`-like thingies that are optimized for being thrown around in huge numbers without all the overhead associated with full-blown sprite nodes.
- Emitters can be built in a visual designer in XCode, which saves a lot of time compared to programmatically creating everything.

However, I already found myself in a situation once where I was forced to implement my own "emitter." In my case, it involved little more than writing a method creating a fixed number of sprite nodes, and attaching a complex action (three levels of hierarchy of multiple groups and sequences) to each of them that controlled their movement, scale, alpha, and eventual disappearance (removal from parent). It was not a huge amount of work, and it gave me the precise control I needed over the particle animations that an emitter node couldn't provide – but I was lucky in that I only needed to emit a few dozen particles at a time.

I'd say implementing your own emitter would make the most sense if all of the following conditions are true:

- You really need texture animation and can't wait for Apple to fix that bug, and/or you need some other particle behaviors that `SKEmitterNode` doesn't provide; *and*
- you don't need a huge number of particles, especially concurrent particles (so that performance remains acceptable); *and*
- you don't mind doing all the emitter design work programmatically, without the visual designer – although you can still prototype your emitter as an `SKEmitterNode` in Xcode, and re-use the parameters of your prototype in your final implementation; *and*
- your particle animations (i.e. all changes in position, scale, alpha, rotation, tint, texture (the reason why you'd do this in the first place)) are not too overwhelming to specify all: in my case, I only had to implement one special case (whose complexity I could still manage), but if I'd had a need to design multiple emitters like this, I would have probably ended up creating a class with an API comparable to that of `SKEmitterNode`, which may not be a trivial task.

Once again, good luck: `SpriteKit` could be a fantastic framework if only Apple got around to fixing some of its pretty outrageous bugs. (I'm having issues with custom shaders… Maybe you will see a question or two from me in the near future.)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working. Did you get it working somehow? I tried setting the particleTexture property to nil. Also, I tried: emitter.run(animationAction) but nothing seems to be working. No one else posted anything helpful elsewhere, that I can find. A lot of people are complaining about bugs.

Comment: @Joe – I'm sorry, you're right: as it turns out `particleAction` doesn't work, and hasn't worked in years. I tried everything to get it to work, but it just won't. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! On another post where somebody's trying to do something similar, a user said what I'm attempting could be achieved with a Shader. When I looked into shaders it seems pretty complex, my app is more of an ARKit app, I'm not that familiar with SpriteKit, and shaders look like something completely different. Anyway, can the particles be changed using Shaders? Here's the post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35769213/spritekit-particle-emitter-multi-image#comment112747392_35769213

Comment: Oh boy… shaders have a bit of a learning curve, you need to learn a new programming language and tell each pixel what to draw based on its coordinates… I can try if emitters work with shaders (can't trust what Apple says about this stuff…) What kind of effect are you trying to achieve? Can you say a bit more?

Comment: Don't worry about. It's not a big part of the app. I'm going to submit this bug to Apple. Hopefully, they will fix it soon. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
  let image1 = SKAction.run( { emitter.particleTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "image1") } )
  let image2 = SKAction.run( { emitter.particleTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "image2") } )
  let image3 = SKAction.run( { emitter.particleTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "image3") } )
  
  let seq = SKAction.sequence([image1, wait, image2, wait, image3, wait])
  let repeater = SKAction.repeatForever(seq)
  emitter.run(repeater)
```